# stack overflow issue with byte framebuffer array fill command

Tags: java, stack-overflow

Hey guys Im currently working on my own custom frame buffer and drawing primitives into it. Which is working fine.

My issue however is filling primitives as a solid colour on the screen. Such as a circle in this case.

The issue is went im trying to fill it that I gain a stack overflow error(which means the recursive function never ends).

here is the recursive function im using to fill the area...

```
private void filler(int position, byte r, byte g, byte b)
{

    buffer[position] = r;
    buffer[position + 1] = g;
    buffer[position + 2] = b;
    int northPosition = position - rowLength;
    int southPosition = position + rowLength;
    int westPosition = position - 3;
    int eastPosition = position + 3;
    //fills squares west of the current
    /**/
    System.out.println(position);
    //fills squares to the east of the current 
    if(buffer[eastPosition] != r && buffer[eastPosition + 1] != g && buffer[eastPosition + 2] != b)
    {
        System.out.println("runs");
        filler(eastPosition, r, g, b);
    }
    System.out.println(position);
    //fills squares north of the current
    if(buffer[northPosition] != r && buffer[northPosition + 1] != g && buffer[northPosition + 2] != b)
    {
        filler(northPosition,r,g,b);
    }
    //fills squares south of current
    if(buffer[southPosition] != r && buffer[southPosition + 1] != g && buffer[southPosition + 2] != b)
    {
        filler(southPosition,r,g,b);
    }
    //fills squares  west of current
    if(buffer[westPosition] != r && buffer[westPosition + 1] != g && buffer[westPosition + 2] != b)
    {   
        filler(westPosition, r, g, b);
    }
}
```

Please note that north and south parts of the code works perfectly fine, and the error only occurs when the east and west parts of the code works together(But they work fine by themselves if i remove one or the other from the function). If someone see's the problem can you please explain to me why east and west affects eachother if possible?

Much thanks!

Comment: What is a sample input to `filler()`?

Comment: cos its in bytes and it pics a specific position. it could be 23345,200,0,0

Comment: Did you east/west without south/north?

Comment: interesting, just tried that now and it seemed to do east and west fine. with north and south code removed that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method never returns. Every point you fill typically has at least 1 pixel next to it, so the method will not return for the moment, but instead go down the call stack to fill this pixel. This leads to very deep call stack and the stackoverflow limits the size of the area to be filled. So if you want use java and fill large areas you should consider another algorithm.

Comment: yeah the more i look at it, the more it seems it is just reaching the stack trace. It can partially fill the circle if one of the statements are removed... I dont exactly want to give up on this method yet however.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to implement the Floodfill algorithm (see the [german Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floodfill) for a nice pseudo code implementation). As you are apparently using a one-dimensional array, you have to make sure that you so not cross rows (in the east/west case) or the boundary of the array (For all cases).

You only want to advance in east/west direction if the next step will be in the same row as the current pixel AND if it lies inside the borders of the array. So I would change your code like this (I didn't test it):

```
private void filler(int position, byte r, byte g, byte b)
{

    buffer[position] = r;
    buffer[position + 1] = g;
    buffer[position + 2] = b;
    int northPosition = position - rowLength;
    int southPosition = position + rowLength;
    int westPosition = position - 3;
    int eastPosition = position + 3;
    //fills squares west of the current
    /**/
    System.out.println(position);
    //fills squares to the east of the current 
    if(eastPosition < buffer.length && eastPosition/rowLength == position/rowLength && buffer[eastPosition] != r && buffer[eastPosition + 1] != g && buffer[eastPosition + 2] != b)
    {
        System.out.println("runs");
        filler(eastPosition, r, g, b);
    }
    System.out.println(position);
    //fills squares north of the current
    if(northPosition >= 0 && buffer[northPosition] != r && buffer[northPosition + 1] != g && buffer[northPosition + 2] != b)
    {
        filler(northPosition,r,g,b);
    }
    //fills squares south of current
    if(southPosition < buffer.length && buffer[southPosition] != r && buffer[southPosition + 1] != g && buffer[southPosition + 2] != b)
    {
        filler(southPosition,r,g,b);
    }
    //fills squares  west of current
    if(westPosition >= 0 && westPosition/rowLength == position/rowLength && buffer[westPosition] != r && buffer[westPosition + 1] != g && buffer[westPosition + 2] != b)
    {   
        filler(westPosition, r, g, b);
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah that looks to be what i am attempting to use. and to ensure i don't, i am checking for the same color for what im placing down before moving to the next position, thus the if statements. At this point im assuming its becoming so recursive its reaching the stack trace limit.. which is how its looking to be more and more as i look at it..

Comment: Crossing the rows was my first idea to, but the entire thing will only work with a complete border or it rund into ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions.

Comment: hmm i think i see what your trying there. However west/north/south/east position only tell it which direction it needs to move in. 
its +3 in the original because in the byte array one position is 3 bytes( red,blue, green ). I chose to determine its boundaries using the rbg because they are the same colour as the fill colour. Will try it anyway tho.*edit* yeah created an index out of bounds error =/

Answer (score 0):

Add boundary conditions too: is there a south/north/east/west position?

Otherwise going west will jump north, and so on, giving easy recursion.
Also once without recursion, index out of bounds should happen.

Comment: the boundary conditions are the if conditionals. the outline of the shape is the same r,g,b coloring in them, making it effectively act as a boundary.

Comment: In that case I can only see one issue: `rowLength` not being a three-fold. Maybe it is `rowLength * 3`?